# Create a popup window in Qt without a shadow

Tags: qt, popup, popupwindow

I'm developing an application using Qt 4.5 (under Windows Vista but want it to be cross platform). I'm using C++

I'd like to create a popup window that that contains a QLineEdit widget, with the feature that when the user interacts with the QLineEdit widget, the popup window is not activated (the main application window remains active).

Creating a window (widget) with the Qt::Popup | Qt::Window flags gives me exactly what I want, except i don't want the 3D shadow border effect this provides. I want a borderless window. Note that the Qt::FramelessWindowHint flag doesn't achieve this.

Anyone got any clues?

Further clarification: Below is a snippit from a simple test application that creates a window with a button in it. When the button is pressed, a popup window is shown and the user can type into a QLineEdit box. When the user does this, the main window remains activated:

http://howlettresearch.com/popup_img_1.png

However, note the shadow border on the popup window (I have been unable to get rid of this).

By comparison, creating the window as in the commented out line allows a popup style window to be created without a shadow, but when the user clicks on the QLineEdit in the popup, the main window is no longer active. You can tell because the shadow on the main window has changed.

http://howlettresearch.com/popup_img_2.png

I'm really after a popup window which behaves as if it is part of the main window. As a side note, the popup window disappears when clicking outside it, but this is almost the behavior I want and I can work with this and grabMouse etc. to do what I want... provided I can get rid of that shadow!

```
PopupTest::PopupTest(QWidget *parent, Qt::WFlags flags)
    : QMainWindow(parent, flags)
{
    QPushButton* pb = new QPushButton("test button");
    setCentralWidget(pb);
    QObject::connect(pb, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(handleClick()));
}

void PopupTest::handleClick()
{
    //QFrame* popup1 = new QFrame(this, Qt::Tool | Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    QFrame* popup1 = new QFrame(this, Qt::Popup | Qt::Window );
    popup1->resize(150,100);
    QLineEdit *tmpE = new QLineEdit( popup1 );
    connect( tmpE, SIGNAL( returnPressed() ), popup1, SLOT( hide() ) );
    tmpE->setGeometry(10,10, 130, 30);
    tmpE->setFocus();
    popup1->show();
}

PopupTest::~PopupTest()
{

}
```

Comment: A screenshot of what you have an what you need would be helpful.

Comment: A top-level widget shadow is something that Windows draws, depending on the theme. There is nothing Qt-specific there.

Answer (score 6):

I worked out a solution to the question I posted earlier.

First, a popup widget can be created by deriving from `QWidget` with flags `Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint`. I actually hacked `qwidget_win.cpp` to ensure my window has the same style and extended style as the Popup control provided by WPF (0x96000000 and 0x08000088 respectively), as determined using Spy++, however I don't think that should matter.

Setting the window style doesn't solve the Window activation problem. The key to doing this to intercept the windows messages that inform the main window that it's non-client area should be updated (`WM_NCACTIVATE` message). This can be done by providing a custom implementation of `QApplication::winEventFilter(MSG* msg, long* result)`.

Unfortunately, simply eating inactivate `WM_ NCACTIVATE` messages isn't enough, because it seems to prevent `WM_ACTIVATE` and other messages that otherwise get generated from being sent to the popup window. To solve this, I have a proof of concept working where I generate the required windows messages in `winEventFilter` after having caught an appropriate `WM_NCACTIVATE` message.

From here, there are some details to work through to make sure it's robust (intercept `WM_ACTIVATEAPP` comes to mind), and then wrap it up into something nice and reusable.

All this is windows specific of course, be interesting to see if there are issues under Linux.

All this is a bit of a pain. Hope I didn't miss something obvious...

Answer (score 4):

Try this strange code bellow (Tested on Qt v5.*):

```
//BasePopup.h
#ifndef BASEPOPUP_H
#define BASEPOPUP_H
#include <QFrame>

class BasePopup : public QFrame
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit BasePopup(QWidget* parent = nullptr);
};

#endif // BASEPOPUP_H
```

```
//BasePopup.cpp
#include "BasePopup.h"

BasePopup::BasePopup(QWidget *parent)
    : QFrame(parent, Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint)
{
    /*setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);*/ /* if need transparent background; 
    set this attribute in another place create window with black background */
    show();       // must be, if not system shadow occur :) I don't know why
    setWindowFlags(Qt::Popup | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    show();
    //---------------------- 
    //yours code here 
    //----------------------
}
```

Works only with this sequence methods call. If make something change, we had popup with shadow. ( Magic :))) )

#### Edit

I find this flag `Qt::NoDropShadowWindowHint` in enum `Qt::WindowFlags` (Qt v5.3).
Which appeared in one version of Qt v5.*.
With this flag above code must look something like this.

```
//BasePopup.cpp
#include "BasePopup.h"

BasePopup::BasePopup(QWidget *parent)
    : QFrame(parent, Qt::Popup | Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::NoDropShadowWindowHint)
{
    //---------------------- 
    //yours code here 
    //----------------------
}
```

I not tested yet, but i think it must work.

Answer (score 2):

I am thinking the shadow that you see is related to the Windows theme that you are using. I am using the Windows Classic Theme here and i don't see any shadows :)

Anyways, what if you connect the textChanged() SIGNAL of the QLineEdit into a custom action that restores the focus of the Main Window?
Something like:

```
void PopupTest::handleClick()
{
   QFrame* popup1 = new QFrame(this, Qt::Tool | Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
   popup1->resize(150,100);
   QLineEdit *tmpE = new QLineEdit( popup1 );
   connect( tmpE, SIGNAL( returnPressed() ), popup1, SLOT( hide() ) );
   connect( tmpE, SIGNAL( textChanged(const QString&)), this, SLOT( setActive() ) );
   tmpE->setGeometry(10,10, 130, 30);
   tmpE->setFocus();
   popup1->show();
}

void MainWindow::setActive()
{
   this->activateWindow();
}
```

You will have to create a slot called setActive() and you should also put the QLineEdit into your class header so that from the setActive() function you can do something like:

```
tmpE->setFocus();
```

to restore the focus on the QLineEdit as well.

Comment: The problem with this is the text box then looses focus, so the user can't enter more text without re-activating the popup again.. 

I think you are right about the shadow being part of the windows theme.